# Wait for All Loop Results Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, last.fm

I loop through an array and call the function 'getTopTracks', which makes a json request (using a LastFM wrapper plugin https://github.com/fxb/javascript-last.fm-api). Then I store that information in a new array "tracks_all".

How do I wait until the results from each API call are finished before doing something with the "tracks_all" array?

```
// array of last.fm usernames
var user_list = ['user1', 'user2','etc'];

// get top tracks
var getTopTracks = function( user, callback ){
  var last_fm;

  last_fm = new LastFM({
    apiKey    : //apikey,
    apiSecret : //apiSecret
  });

  // method of last.fm api
  last_fm.user.getTopTracks({
    user   : user,
    period : //period,
    limit  : //num of tracks
  }, {
    success: function( data ){
      var track_arr;
      track_arr = data.toptracks.track;
      callback( track_arr );
    },
    error: function( code, message ){}
  });

};

var newFetch = function(){
  var user_list_len,
      i, 
      tracks_all = [];

  user_list_len = user_list.length;

  for( i = 0; i < user_list_len; i++ ){
    getTopTracks(
      user_list[ i ],
      function( data ){
        var track_data = data;
        // combine into one big array
        tracks_all.push.apply( tracks_all, track_data );
      });
  }
};

// What I want to do is something like...
var get_tracks = newFetch();

// if the loop is done and all results are in
//    call the function outputToDom()
```

Comment: You can use deferreds, see here http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: And use `when` with those deferreds: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Not really sure how to hook that up to my code. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `Promise` style using `when`

```
// array of last.fm usernames
var user_list = ['user1', 'user2','etc'];

// get top tracks
var getTopTracks = function( user ){
  var last_fm;
  var deferred = when.defer();

  last_fm = new LastFM({
    apiKey    : //apikey,
    apiSecret : //apiSecret
  });

  // method of last.fm api
  last_fm.user.getTopTracks({
    user   : user,
    period : //period,
    limit  : //num of tracks
  }, {
    success: function( data ){
      var track_arr;
      track_arr = data.toptracks.track;
      deferred.resolve(track_arr);
    },
    error: function( code, message ){
      deferred.reject(code);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise();
};

var newFetch = function(){
  var deferred = when.defer();
  var promises = [];
  user_list.forEach(function(user){
    promises.push(getTopTracks(user));
  });

  when.all(promises, function(results){
    // results will be an array of track_arr
    deferred.resolve(results);
  }, function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};

// What I want to do is something like...
var get_tracks = newFetch();

get_tracks.done(function(results){
  // results will be an array of track_arr
}, function(error){
  // handle error
});
```

And this is the `Callback` style using `async`

```
// array of last.fm usernames
var user_list = ['user1', 'user2','etc'];

// get top tracks
var getTopTracks = function( user, callback ){
  var last_fm;
  var deferred = when.defer();

  last_fm = new LastFM({
    apiKey    : //apikey,
    apiSecret : //apiSecret
  });

  // method of last.fm api
  last_fm.user.getTopTracks({
    user   : user,
    period : //period,
    limit  : //num of tracks
  }, {
    success: function( data ){
      var track_arr;
      track_arr = data.toptracks.track;
      callback(null, track_arr)
    },
    error: function( code, message ){
      callback(code);
    }
  });
};

var newFetch = function(callback){
  var functions = [];
  user_list.forEach(function(user){
    functions.push(getTopTracks(user));
  });

  async.parallel(functions, callback);
};

// What I want to do is something like...
newFetch(function(error, results){
  // results will be an array of track_arr
});
```

Update syntax

Comment: Thanks. When I try with "when.defer()" it returns an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: when is not defined

Comment: You need to manually include `when` library from here https://github.com/cujojs/when . `async` can be found here https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many times the function `getTopTracks` is going to be executed, you can use a counter to keep track of how many more executions of `getTopTracks` are left to perform.

In `newFetch()` :

```
var newFetch = function () {
  var user_list_len,
    i,
    tracks_all = [];

  user_list_len = user_list.length;
  var cpt = user_list.length;              // N executions left
  for (i = 0; i < user_list_len; i++) {
    getTopTracks(
      user_list[i],
      function (data) {
        var track_data = data;
        // combine into one big array
        tracks_all.push.apply(tracks_all, track_data);
        --cpt;                             // One execution has finished
        if (cpt === 0) {                   // 0 execution left
          outputToDom();                   //  -> Call the final callback
        }
      });
  }
};
```